# How do I find out what library to add and what version I need to specify in my project.json file for ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

If I were to add a library to my MVC 6 project.json file, how do I find out the name of the correct library that I need as well as the associated version number? I am not getting proper AutoComplete and the libraries that I need aren't being found (i think). Please see the image below, the tutorial I am watching along needs the Identity library, but I am not sure of the latest version or the proper library name.

[image]

Update: I don't get intellisense for the packages that I am looking for, eg. I wanted to add "EntitFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer" but I got no intellisense to show me that library nor the version.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you're not getting proper auto-complete? You should be able to get intellisense by clicking in the dependencies node and attempt to add a new library by typing letter 'a'  or 'b' etc to get lists that start with that letter alphabetically.  What about using "Manage NuGet packages" when you right click on the project node?

Comment: @SteveKennedy I updated the original post with an example of trying to add EF...when I type in EntityFramework. I don't see intellisense for EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer which is the library that I want to add.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have any special add-ons that might be replacing the default intellisense? I know Resharper and CodeRush both replace the default instellisense. You definitely should be getting more then that (screenshot).   What do you see when you browse: https://api-v3search-0.nuget.org/autocomplete and https://nuget-prod-0-v2searchwebsite.azurewebsites.net/search/query

Comment: I do have CodeRush (not the Roslyn version) installed, but I have tried testing with Visual Studio in SafeMode and I have the same exact issue. When you use it on your system and type EntityFramework...do you see EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer as on of the Intellisense options?

Comment: Yep. Absolutely. I have the same two folders you do, but a ton of other options including the EntityFamework.MicrosoftSqlServer.

Answer (score 1):

A site is temporarily set up by Microsoft at

http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net

Search for the class you want to use and it will tell which package to use for RC1.

They will make it part of VS some time.

Comment: This at least helps me narrow down the package externally, but it still doesn't solve my VS2015 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try supplying a list of package sources to look for vnext packages. I believe this is checked in the order that they are listed.

Create a NuGet.Config entry under Solution items with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <packageSources>
      <add key="VNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json" />
      <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
   </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make sure package sources are enabled/checked in Visual Studio under Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources.

My Machine-wide Packages/Microsoft and .NET was not checked (which is kinda strange because I did do a default install) but checking that solved my issue.

[image]